# nodeSelector constraint ignored on AKS on mixed node pools (windows/linux)?

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

Tried installing a basic Nginx ingress using Helm by running the following command:

```
 helm install nginx-ingress --namespace ingress-basic ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
          --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP='52.232.109.226' \
          --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"='linux' \
          --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"='linux' \
          --set controller.replicaCount=1 \
          --set rbac.create=true
```

Shortly after installing I noticed the pod was scheduled onto a Windows node instead of a Linux node:

```
wesley@Azure:~$ kubectl get pods -n ingress-basic -o wide
NAME                                                 READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE   IP       NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-create-jcp6x   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          18s   <none>   akswin000002   <none>           <none>
```

```
wesley@Azure:~$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                                STATUS   ROLES   AGE     VERSION    INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                         KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
aks-agentpool-59412422-vmss000000   Ready    agent   5h32m   v1.17.11   10.240.0.4     <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS               4.15.0-1096-azure   docker://19.3.12
aks-linuxpool-59412422-vmss000000   Ready    agent   5h32m   v1.17.11   10.240.0.128   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS               4.15.0-1096-azure   docker://19.3.12
akswin000000                        Ready    agent   5h28m   v1.17.11   10.240.0.35    <none>        Windows Server 2019 Datacenter   10.0.17763.1397     docker://19.3.11
akswin000001                        Ready    agent   5h28m   v1.17.11   10.240.0.66    <none>        Windows Server 2019 Datacenter   10.0.17763.1397     docker://19.3.11
akswin000002                        Ready    agent   5h28m   v1.17.11   10.240.0.97    <none>        Windows Server 2019 Datacenter   10.0.17763.1397     docker://19.3.11
```

Running a `describe` on the nginx pod revealed that the field `Node-selectors` remains to be set to `<none>.`

```
Name:               nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-create-jcp6x
Namespace:          ingress-basic
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               akswin000002/10.240.0.97
Start Time:         Fri, 16 Oct 2020 20:09:36 +0000
Labels:             app.kubernetes.io/component=admission-webhook
                    app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx-ingress
                    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                    app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
                    app.kubernetes.io/version=0.40.2
                    controller-uid=d03091cd-8138-4923-a369-afeca669099c
                    helm.sh/chart=ingress-nginx-3.7.1
                    job-name=nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-create
Annotations:        <none>
**Status:             Pending**
IP:                
Controlled By:      Job/nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-create
Containers:
  create:
    Container ID: 
    Image:         docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.3.0
    Image ID:     
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      create
      --host=nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission,nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission.$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc
      --namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)
      --secret-name=nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      POD_NAMESPACE:  ingress-basic (v1:metadata.namespace)
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-token-8x6ct (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-token-8x6ct:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-token-8x6ct
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
**Node-Selectors:  <none>**
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                  From                   Message
  ----     ------                  ----                 ----                   -------
  Normal   SandboxChanged          5m (x5401 over 2h)   kubelet, akswin000002  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  31s (x5543 over 2h)  kubelet, akswin000002  (combined from similar events): Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-admission-create-jcp6x": Error response from daemon: container a734c23d20338d7fed800752c19f5e94688fd38fe82c9e90fc14533bae90c6bc encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The user name or password is incorrect. (0x52e) extra info: {"CommandLine":"cmd /S /C pauseloop.exe","User":"2000","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\","Environment":{"PATH":"c:\\Windows\\System32;c:\\Windows"},"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}
```

I expected the pod to be scheduled onto a Linux node instead. Does anyone have a clue why this is happening? I saw no taints or anything and this is just a newly spin up cluster. The only workaround for now seems to be to scale the windows node back to 0. Install nginx ingress and then scale up the windows nodes again.

- Kubernetes version: 1.17.11

Comment: I did some further digging and I found out that when we use helm template instead of helm install and inspect the resources in the generated .yaml file we can see that the nodeSelector property is only specified for kind: Deployment and none of the other resources it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Works with below. Added admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic#create-an-ingress-controller

```
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace ingress-basic \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux
```